# Is Weld an Java SE Runtime environment or a container for Java SE?

Tags: weld, jboss-weld

What exactly is [Weld](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/) ?

Is Weld an Java SE runtime by itself or it is only a container which can be used in my existing JRE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weld is not a Java SE runtime.

Weld is an implementation of [cdi-specification 1.0](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/) and later versions of that.

`WELD-SE` is a container for CDI-Beans running in an existing JRE.

More often Weld is used as module in other containers like Glassfish, JBoss7, Wildfly to manage CDI-Beans according to the JSR-Spec.

Comment: doesn't latest JDK/JRE instances themselves support CDI Specs ? why do we additionally need Weld ?

Comment: JAVA-EE contains the specifications of cdi. Weld itself is a reference implementation of the specification, but afaIk there is no implementation of CDI contained in any JDK-Release.